# Get all information between the same multiple tags from XML file in C

Tags: c, xml, parsing

**Summary:**

- I developed an app which is supposed to: read an **XML File** (**without** using any XML library), get some words between specific tags and print those words on the screen using the basic `printf()`.

My **XML File** looks like this:

```
<Server>  
    <Host>ip1</Host>  
    <User>user1</User>  
    <Pass>pass1</Pass>  
</Server>  
<Server>  
    <Host>ip2</Host>  
    <User>user2</User>  
    <Pass>pass2</Pass>  
</Server>
```

Now, my code is able to get: *ip1, user1, pass1*.

How can I modify my code, so that I can also get *ip2, user2, pass2* then *ip3, user3, pass3* and so on until I reach the end of the file ?

The code is the next one:

```
int getContent()
{
    //variables for reading the XML file
    char *buffer=0;
    long length;
    FILE *xmlFile=fopen("C:/Users/IEUser/AppData/Roaming/recentservers.xml","r");

    //constants for parsing XML
    const char *HOSTSTART = "<Host>";
    const char *HOSTEND = "</Host>";

    const char *USERSTART = "<User>";
    const char *USEREND = "</User>";

    const char *PASSSTART = "<Pass encoding=\"base64\">";
    const char *PASSEND = "</Pass>";

    char *target_host = NULL,*target_user = NULL,*target_pass = NULL, *start, *end;

    //read the xml file
    if(xmlFile)
    {
        fseek(xmlFile,0,SEEK_END);
        length=ftell(xmlFile);
        fseek(xmlFile,0,SEEK_SET);

        buffer=malloc(length);
        if(buffer)
        {
            fread(buffer,1,length,xmlFile);
        }
        fclose(xmlFile);
    }

    //get the HOST
    if(buffer)
    {
        if(start=strstr(buffer,HOSTSTART))
        {
            start += strlen(HOSTSTART);
            if(end=strstr(start, HOSTEND))
            {
                target_host = (char *)malloc(end-start+1);
                memcpy(target_host,start,end-start);
                target_host[end-start]='\0';
            }
        }
        if(target_host)
            printf("%s\n",target_host);
        //free(target_host);
    }

    //get the USER
    if(buffer)
    {
        if(start=strstr(buffer,USERSTART))
        {
            start += strlen(USERSTART);
            if(end=strstr(start, USEREND))
            {
                target_user = (char *)malloc(end-start+1);
                memcpy(target_user,start,end-start);
                target_user[end-start]='\0';
            }
        }
        if(target_user)
            printf("%s\n",target_user);
        //free(target_user);
    }

    //get the PASS
    if(buffer)
    {
        if(start=strstr(buffer,PASSSTART))
        {
            start += strlen(PASSSTART);
            if(end=strstr(start, PASSEND))
            {
                target_pass = (char *)malloc(end-start+1);
                memcpy(target_pass,start,end-start);
                target_pass[end-start]='\0';
            }
        }
        if(target_pass)
            printf("%s\n",target_pass);
        //free(target_pass);
    }
    // here I would like a for which will printf as many target information as they are in that XML File
    printf("%s | %s | %s",target_host,target_user,target_pass);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    getContent();
    return 0;
}
```

---

**//EDIT1:**

```
int readTag(char *buffer, const char *tagStart, const char *tagEnd){
    int start, end;
    char *target = NULL;
    start = 0;
    end = 0;
    if(start=strstr(buffer,tagStart))
    {
        start += strlen(tagStart);
        if(end=strstr(start, tagEnd))
        {
            target = malloc(end-start+1); //don't cast malloc
            memcpy(target,start,end-start);
            target[end-start]='\0';
            printf("Target between tag %s and %s = %s", tagStart, tagEnd, target);
            //sendTargetToGET(tagStart, tagEnd, target);
            free(target);
        }
    }
    return (end - start); // returns nr characters between the tags
}

int getTagID(char *buffer){
    const char *HOSTSTART = "<Host>";
    const char *HOSTEND = "</Host>";

    const char *USERSTART = "<User>";
    const char *USEREND = "</User>";

    const char *PASSSTART = "<Pass encoding=\"base64\">";
    const char *PASSEND = "</Pass>";

    if(strstr(buffer, HOSTSTART) != NULL && strstr(buffer, HOSTEND) != NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(strstr(buffer, USERSTART) != NULL && strstr(buffer, USEREND) != NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strstr(buffer, PASSSTART) != NULL && strstr(buffer, PASSEND) != NULL)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else 
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char *buffer=0;

    const char *HOSTSTART = "<Host>";
    const char *HOSTEND = "</Host>";

    const char *USERSTART = "<User>";
    const char *USEREND = "</User>";

    const char *PASSSTART = "<Pass encoding=\"base64\">";
    const char *PASSEND = "</Pass>";
    FILE *xmlFile=fopen("C:/Users/IEUser/AppData/Roaming/recentservers.xml","r");

    int tagID = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), xmlFile) != NULL)
    {
         tagID = getTagID(buffer);

         if(tagID == 1)
         {
             readTag(buffer, HOSTSTART, HOSTEND);
         }
         else if(tagID == 2)
         {
             readTag(buffer, USERSTART, USEREND);
         }
         else if(tagID == 3)
         {

         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've got an assertion failure unfortunately and I don't know what is the reason

Comment: Why don't you use any existing `xml` parser? For your parser, search for tags (anything betwee `<...>`) and text i.e. everything else and use a recursive function to store it in a tree format.

Comment: Why can't you use any XML library? If you want a robust solution you will end up with writing one on your own.

Comment: @MohitJain there are more tags not only `host`, `user`, `pass`but I just simplified it for the sake of example and because the only ones that I need. Could you please provide a detailed answer ?

Comment: Have you ever heard of function arguments and loops? You are doing fine, just make another function that searches for  `<Server>` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest is:

**1)** Put the tag read parts in a function so you can don't have the same code for every tag:

```
int readTag(char *buffer, const char *tagStart, const char *tagEnd){
    int start, end;
    char *target = NULL;
    start = 0;
    end = 0;
    if(start=strstr(buffer,tagStart))
    {
        start += strlen(tagStart);
        if(end=strstr(start, tagEnd))
        {
            target = malloc(end-start+1); //don't cast malloc
            memcpy(target,start,end-start);
            target[end-start]='\0';
            printf("Target between tag %s and %s = %s", tagStart, tagEnd, target);
            //sendTargetToGET(tagStart, tagEnd, target);
            free(target);
        }
    }
    return (end - start); // returns nr characters between the tags
}
```

**2)** Read the file line by line, check if the line contains tags you need (maybe with a function) and call the associated tag read function.

```
int tagID = 0;
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), xmlFile) != NULL){
     tagID = getTagID(buffer);

     if(tagID == 1){//or use an enum here
         readTag(buffer, HOSTSTART, HOSTEND);
     }else if(tagID == 2){
         readTag(buffer, USERSTART, USEREND);
     }else if(tagID == 3){ //and so on
     }
}

int getTagID(char *buffer){
    if(strstr(buffer, HOSTSTART) != NULL && strstr(buffer, HOSTEND) != NULL){
        return 1;
    }else if(strstr(buffer, USERSTART) != NULL && strstr(buffer, USERSTART) != NULL){
        return 2;
    }else if(/*and so on*/){
    }else return 0;
}
```

Comment: nice. What happens to `target`? It's allocated, printed, but not freed. It' unclear what the OP wants to do with it

Comment: @Pynchia Whoops forgot the freeing.. thanks for pointing that out! Well in his question he tells he only wants to print it so I guess this is OK as far as I am informed.

Comment: @moffeltje I don't have any `getTagID()` function (could you help me a little bit with that too ?). More, for now I just want them printed. LAter, I will send this information in a GET request.

Comment: The naming "*Tag ID*" is missleading. It's about the "*element's name*" which **is** the "*tag*".

Comment: @Alexander I've just provided some idea's with some untested code to give you an idea how to write your program. The task of get it working is yours now, I do not have the time to write and debug a program you need.

Comment: @moffeltje Yes, I know. I don't want you to do this. I was just wondering if I wrote the `main()` and other functions as you were expecting to be writen.

Comment: @Alexander Well yeah, that is indeed the way I think your program can be implemented. Of course it is your decision and you should consider if it meets the criteria of your program. Good luck and if this answered your question, you can accept it!

Comment: @moffeltje. I accepted your answer. Thanks very much for your collaboration. I have a last question if that's possible and you have time: how would the `main()` of the program look like ? I'm mostly interested in the arguments of the functions.